# c: free char* without destroying char**

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

What I want to do is allocate a `char** stringarr`.

On some places, `stringarr[index]`, I want to assign a `char*`.
So I want to save strings(`char*`) in some places of the `char **`.
For example after the program has run:

```
stringarr[0] = "Hello", stringarr[1] = "goodbye"
```

The problem is that I want to free the `char *` holding the strings, but when I do of course `stringarr[0]` no longer will point to the freed `char*`.

How can I solve this?

To clarify:
I want to add strings(char*) to a string array (char**). Then I free the strings, but not the string array. How can I do this, without affecting the char**?

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The above code sets `stringarr[0]` to point to a string literal, which cannot be freed. The most you can do is set `stringarr[0]` to something else, such as `NULL`. If instead, you do something like `char *foo = malloc(10); strcpy(foo, "fred"); stringarr[0] = foo;`, and you later call `free(foo)`, it is up to your code to ensure that it never accesses the buffer pointed to by `stringarr[0]`. How you accomplish that is up to you. Making sure your code resets `stringarr[0] = NULL;` after freeing `foo`, and always always checking whether `stringarr[0]` is NULL or not, is one way to accomplish it.

Comment: The question is unclear as freeing memory depends on how it was allocated. Please post more code.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to handle this is to assign `NULL` to the freed pointer(s):

```
free(stringarr[3]);
stringarr[3] = NULL;
```

You can still access the other strings in `stringarr` (but not `stringarr[3]`) and you can check whether a specific position is vacant by checking if it is `NULL`.

Comment: how can this possibly work? I have char ** stringarr, on place stringarr[0] I have a char* tmp. Then I free stringarr[0] and set it to NULL? And still I have the string in 0 and the string is freed?

Comment: You want to keep the strings?  Then either don't free them or use `strdup` to create a copy.

Comment: Yes I want to keep the strings in the stringarr, since I return the stringarr from the method.

Comment: Then why free them? Isn't it better to leave that to the calling code?

Comment: The calling code will only have access to the strarr**? Not the char*s

Comment: @p3ob2lem maybe uou can post your f...nny code that can clear or doubts...

Comment: The calling code has access to the `char*`s through the `strarr**`.  Post your code and it will be easier to clear your doubts.